# How were the default values of the remediation function estimated in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, static-code-analysis, sonarqube5.6

We are using SonarQube 5.6 LTS in my project. There is a remediation function(effort required to fix the violation) for each issue, a value given in minutes. I want to understand how, the effort estimation was done.

For instance, a Java issue, ***Math operands should be cast before assignment*** has a remediation function of 5 minutes per issue. How was this 5 minutes calculated/estimated ?
Are there any formulas for this ?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is less scientific than I'm sure you're hoping for. Essentially it's a gut feeling estimate of how long it will take the average developer on the average day in an average project. You may take more time or less depending on any of a dozen factors. But if you feel an estimate is just flat wrong, you should open a new thread about it on the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube)

Full disclosure: for many of these it's my gut that was checked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @G.Ann !